# Attributes from Boost.Spirit grammar: error from std:vector of boost::variant

Tags: c++, boost, c++14, abstract-syntax-tree, boost-spirit-x3

I got a working parser for reading position descriptions for a board game (international draughts, [official grammar](http://pdn.fmjd.org/fen.html)):

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

auto const colon   = x3::lit(':');
auto const comma   = x3::lit(',');
auto const dash    = x3::lit('-');
auto const dot     = x3::lit('.');    
auto const king    = x3::char_('K');
auto const color   = x3::char_("BW");
auto const num_sq  = x3::int_;

auto const num_pc  = -king >> num_sq;               // Kxx means king on square xx, xx a man on that square
auto const num_rng = num_pc >> dash >> num_sq;      // xx-yy means range of squares xx through yy (inclusive)
auto const num_seq = (num_rng | num_pc) % comma;    // <--- attribute should be std::vector<boost::variant>
auto const ccn     = colon >> color >> -num_seq;
auto const num_not = x3::repeat(2)[ccn];            // need to specify both white and black pieces
auto const fen     = color >> num_not >> -dot;
```

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5a425b9b0dd609a4)</kbd>**

Now I want to extract the values from the synthesized attributes, so I did the boilerplate dance around Boost.Fusion etc.,

```
namespace ast {

struct num_pc  { boost::optional<char> k; int sq; };
struct num_rng { boost::optional<char> k; int first, last; };
using rng_or_pc = boost::variant<num_rng, num_pc>;
struct num_seq { std::vector<rng_or_pc> sqrs; };
struct ccn     { char c; boost::optional<num_seq> seq; };
struct num_not { std::vector<ccn> n; };
struct fen     { char c; num_not n; };

}   // namespace ast

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::num_pc,  (boost::optional<char>, k), (int, sq))
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::num_rng, (boost::optional<char>, k), (int, first), (int, last))
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::num_seq, (std::vector<ast::rng_or_pc>, sqrs))
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::ccn,     (char, c), (boost::optional<ast::num_seq>, seq))
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::num_not, (std::vector<ast::ccn>, n))
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::fen,     (char, c), (ast::num_not, n))

x3::rule<class num_pc_class,  ast::num_pc > num_pc  = "num_pc";
x3::rule<class num_rng_class, ast::num_rng> num_rng = "num_rng";
x3::rule<class num_seq_class, ast::num_seq> num_seq = "num_seq";
x3::rule<class ccn_class,     ast::ccn    > ccn     = "ccn";
x3::rule<class num_not_class, ast::num_not> num_not = "num_not";
x3::rule<class fen_class,     ast::fen    > fen     = "fen";

auto const colon   = x3::lit(':');
auto const comma   = x3::lit(',');
auto const dash    = x3::lit('-');
auto const dot     = x3::lit('.');    
auto const king    = x3::char_('K');
auto const color   = x3::char_("BW");
auto const num_sq  = x3::int_;

auto const num_pc_def  = -king >> num_sq;
auto const num_rng_def = num_pc >> dash >> num_sq;
auto const num_seq_def = (num_rng | num_pc) % comma;
auto const ccn_def     = colon >> color >> -num_seq;
auto const num_not_def = x3::repeat(2)[ccn];
auto const fen_def     = color >> num_not >> -dot;

BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(num_pc, num_rng, num_seq, ccn, num_not, fen)
```

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/088313925606d968)</kbd>**

However, I then get an error saying that

> error: static_assert failed "Attribute does not have the expected
>   size."

and a couple of pages down:

> ^ main.cpp:16:8: note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: no known conversion from
>   '`std::vector<boost::variant<ast::num_rng, ast::num_pc>,
>   std::allocator<boost::variant<ast::num_rng, ast::num_pc> > >`' to
>   'ast::num_seq' for 1st argument struct num_seq {
>   `std::vector<rng_or_pc>` sqrs; };
>
> ^ main.cpp:16:8: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known conversion from
>   '`std::vector<boost::variant<ast::num_rng, ast::num_pc>,
>   std::allocator<boost::variant<ast::num_rng, ast::num_pc> > >`' to
>   'const ast::num_seq' for 1st argument struct num_seq {
>   `std::vector<rng_or_pc>` sqrs; };

**Question**: where is this error coming from, and how to resolve it? Apparently the synthesized attribute of my `num_seq` rule is not equal to `std::vector<boost::variant>>`. How can I correct this?

Comment: [This](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0ed4e50273d9f2c3) seems to work. You had at least two problems. The first one (easy to understand) is that your `num_rng` rule's attribute is basically `tuple<opt<char>,int,int>` but its synthesized attribute is `tuple<tuple<opt<char>,int>,int>`.  In the example I give a possible solution, another could be inlining `num_pc` into `num_rng`. The other I don't fully understand, but seems to be related to the interaction between optional and a single (container) element fusion sequence. Using `using num_seq = vector<rng_or_pc>;` seems to solve it.

Comment: thanks, I will study it more carefully, I had missed the `tuple<opt<char>,int>>` nesting

Comment: @cv_and_he please consider posting these as answers instead ?

Comment: @cv_and_he do you agree that this is still evidence of broken single-element sequences? It appears that even though the non-nested single-element container sequence (`not_num`) is compiling it failed to assign the second item from the `repeat(2)` directive. I'm really out of my depth trying to debug this kind of philosophical design issue in the implementation :(

Comment: @sehe I really don't know, I feel it's more of a problem with the optional part, but removing the fusion sequence from the equation made it work...

Comment: The optional doesn't cause it though. I've reported the issue repeatedly without optional being involved. @cv_and_he

Comment: @sehe In one of my intermediate attempts I removed the optional without changing the adapted struct, and that error also went away(or maybe it was buried under the new errors).

Comment: @cv_and_he I would very much not be surprised if it compiled but didn't work correctly (as with the outer vector)

Comment: @sehe I didn't understand that part of your answer, [my program](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/486f5195f396ac90) gives the exact same results as yours. (Although obviously it's better to just use vector in that situation).

Comment: @cv_and_he ah. That was a bug on my end: compare [bug](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/27ec5f72d026222d) with [fixed](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f96520493149f71c). I'll remove the warning from my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've spent some time trying to understand the grammar.

> *I strongly suggest readable identifiers. It's very hard to understand what's going on, while I have the strong impression it's actually a really simple grammar*

I suggest a simplification version shown below.

- Because your grammar doesn't use recursion there's no real need for the rule and tagged parser types.
- Also use a namespace for the parser artefacts.
- Consider encapsulation the use of a skipper instead of letting the caller decide (`x3::skip[]`)
- Add a few helpers to be able to print the AST for verification:

  ```
  template <typename T> std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, std::vector<T> const& v) {
      os << "{"; for (auto& el : v) os << el << " "; return os << "}";
  }
  std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, num_pc const& p)  { if (p.k) os << p.k; return os << p.sq; }
  std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, num_rng const& r) { return os << r.pc << "-" << r.last; }
  std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, ccn const& o)     { return os << o.c << " " << o.seq;                      } 
  std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, num_not const& nn) { return os << nn.n; }
  ```
- I'd avoid wrapping the other vector unnecessarily too:

  ```
  using num_not = std::vector<ccn>;
  ```
- Use the modern ADAPT macros (as you're using C++14 by definition):

  ```
  BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::num_pc,  k, sq)
  BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::num_rng, pc, last)
  BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::ccn,     c, seq)
  BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::fen,     c, n)
  ```
  -

#### Live Demo

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2143aa51164bcf62)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/as_vector.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/io.hpp>
#include <boost/optional/optional_io.hpp>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

namespace ast {

    struct num_pc {
        boost::optional<char> k;
        int sq;
    };

    struct num_rng {
        num_pc pc;
        int last;
    };

    using rng_or_pc = boost::variant<num_rng, num_pc>;
    using num_seq = std::vector<rng_or_pc>;

    struct ccn {
        char c;
        boost::optional<num_seq> seq;
    };

    using num_not = std::vector<ccn>;

    struct fen {
        char c;
        num_not n;
    };

    template <typename T> std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, std::vector<T> const& v) {
        os << "{"; for (auto& el : v) os << el << " "; return os << "}";
    }
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, num_pc const& p)  { if (p.k) os << p.k; return os << p.sq; }
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, num_rng const& r) { return os << r.pc << "-" << r.last; }
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, ccn const& o)     { return os << o.c << " " << o.seq;                      } 
}

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::num_pc,  k, sq)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::num_rng, pc, last)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::ccn,     c, seq)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::fen,     c, n)

namespace FEN {
    namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

    namespace grammar
    {
        using namespace x3;

        template<typename T>
            auto as = [](auto p) { return rule<struct _, T>{} = as_parser(p); };

        uint_type const number {};
        auto const color   = char_("BW");
        auto const num_pc  = as<ast::num_pc>  ( -char_('K') >> number          ); 
        auto const num_rng = as<ast::num_rng> ( num_pc >> '-' >> number        ); 
        auto const num_seq = as<ast::num_seq> ( (num_rng | num_pc) % ','       ); 
        auto const ccn     = as<ast::ccn>     ( ':' >> color >> -num_seq       ); 
        auto const num_not = as<ast::num_not> ( repeat(2)[ccn]                 ); 
        auto const fen     = as<ast::fen>     ( color >> num_not >> -lit('.')  ); 
    }

    using grammar::fen;
}

int main() {
    for (std::string const t : {
        "B:W18,24,27,28,K10,K15:B12,16,20,K22,K25,K29",
        "B:W18,19,21,23,24,26,29,30,31,32:B1,2,3,4,6,7,9,10,11,12",
        "W:B1-20:W31-50",   // initial position
        "W:B:W",            // empty board
        "W:B1:W",           // only black pieces
        "W:B:W50"           // only white pieces
    }) {
        auto b = t.begin(), e = t.end();
        ast::fen data;
        bool ok = phrase_parse(b, e, FEN::fen, FEN::x3::space, data);

        std::cout << t << "\n";
        if (ok) {
            std::cout << "Parsed: " << boost::fusion::as_vector(data) << "\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << "Parse failed:\n";
            std::cout << "\t on input: " << t << "\n";
        }
        if (b != e)
            std::cout << "\t Remaining unparsed: '" << std::string(b, e) << '\n';
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
B:W18,24,27,28,K10,K15:B12,16,20,K22,K25,K29
Parsed: (B {W  {18 24 27 28  K10  K15 } B  {12 16 20  K22  K25  K29 } })
B:W18,19,21,23,24,26,29,30,31,32:B1,2,3,4,6,7,9,10,11,12
Parsed: (B {W  {18 19 21 23 24 26 29 30 31 32 } B  {1 2 3 4 6 7 9 10 11 12 } })
W:B1-20:W31-50
Parsed: (W {B  {1-20 } W  {31-50 } })
W:B:W
Parsed: (W {B -- W -- })
W:B1:W
Parsed: (W {B  {1 } W -- })
W:B:W50
Parsed: (W {B -- W  {50 } })
```

Comment: thanks a bunch! re: the cryptic notation, yes, I'm guilty, sorry about that. The fen parser essentially enumerate the contents of the board, with B/W modifiers for black / white pieces, and the K modifier for kings (absence = pawn). I used the cryptic "num_" prefix because the full grammar (not shown for brevity) also allows for algebraic notation (as in chess) instead of numbers for squares.

Comment: Ah. I _was_ wondering about the prefix (how about a namespace, maybe, or just longer names :))

Comment: yeah, normally I would do proper naming, but this was a scratch version, fully done online, I had no idea I would actually almost get to the point of doing the attribute extraction on my first try with Boost.Spirit.

Comment: You got that because you defined the ast. As long as your ast is compatible, you're good (personally, I feel you likely want a slightly higherlevel AST, though, because all the optionals are likely slightly awkward to deal with)

Comment: so std::vector and boost::variant/optional are automatically adapted by Boost.Fusion? That's nice, so that I only need to adapt the hand-written structs, and the c++14 auto makes it even nicer.

Comment: These are intrinsic to Spirit's attribute propagation - fusion is not involved.

Comment: @TemplateRex [My attempt](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b65de362b25fa4f1) at the grammar. I haven't used optionals in the ast structures, and so when they aren't present, they are default initialized. You can easily add the optionals if you like.

Comment: @sehe: I also see that you (correctly) use unsigned integers for the squares, but what's the difference between `uint_type const number {};` and `auto const number = uint_;`?

Comment: @TemplateRex `uint_` is defined as `uint_type const uint_ = {};`. So I'd say that both are the same.

Comment: btw, I tend to use `lit()` everywhere in order to forget about mixing in other operators than `>>`

Comment: @TemplateRex better yet, in x3 start into the habit of using `as_parser` for that purpose

Comment: @sehe [see here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ac09c864d2628a73) for a cleaned up version (separate namespaces for algebraic/notation, better naming etc.). Everything parses nicely, but the overloading of the IO operators is not going well (deep errors from boost/optional_io.hpp), [see here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7257f0b1465a4d98). Any ideas? Or should I post a new Q&A?