# Overloaded output operator not found for Boost.Spirit expression

Tags: c++, boost, operator-overloading, c++14, boost-spirit-x3

This is a follow-up on [**this Q&A**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34559607/819272). I now have several data structures in a `namespace ast`, subdivided over two sub-namespaces (`algebraic` and `numeric`) that correspond to the two different formats that the grammar recognizes.

```
namespace ast {    
    namespace algebraic {            
        struct occupance
        { 
            char pc; 
            char col;
            int row; 
        };

        using pieces = std::vector<occupance>;

        struct placement 
        { 
            char c; 
            boost::optional<pieces> p; 
        };        
    }

    namespace numeric {            
        struct occupance
        { 
            char pc; 
            int sq; 
        };

        struct range 
        { 
            occupance oc; 
            int sq; 
        };

        using pieces = std::vector<boost::variant<range, occupance>>;

        struct placement 
        { 
            char c; 
            boost::optional<pieces> p; 
        };            
    }

    struct fen 
    { 
        char c; 
        std::vector<boost::variant<numeric::placement, algebraic::placement>> p; 
    };
}
```

Working parser **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0379fa56293e1f46)</kbd>**

The trouble starts when I try to define streaming operators for the various types. With the generic `operator<<` taking a `vector<T>` in the same namespace as the various `ast` structs (as in the linked Q&A), all is fine. But once I have two sub-namespaces `algebraic` and `numeric` and define the various operators in these namespaces:

```
namespace ast {
    template <typename T> 
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, std::vector<T> const& v) 
    {
        os << "{"; 
        for (auto const& el : v) 
            os << el << " "; 
        return os << "}";
    }        

    namespace algebraic {            
        std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, occupance const& oc)  
        { 
            return os << oc.pc << oc.col << oc.row; 
        }

        std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, placement const& p)     
        { 
            return os << p.c << " " << p.p; 
        }         
    }   // algebriac

    namespace numeric {
        std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, occupance const& oc)  
        { 
            return os << oc.pc << oc.sq; 
        }

        std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, range const& r) 
        { 
            for (auto sq = r.oc.sq; sq <= r.sq; ++sq)
                os << r.oc.pc << sq << " ";
            return os;
        }

        std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, placement const& p)     
        { 
            return os << p.c << " " << p.p; 
        }         
    }   // numeric
}   // ast
```

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9426b71ce57fa838)</kbd>** the appropriate operators are no longer being found.

```
In file included from main.cpp:4:
/usr/local/include/boost/optional/optional_io.hpp:47:21: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >' and 'const std::__1::vector<ast::algebraic::occupance, std::__1::allocator<ast::algebraic::occupance> >')
    else out << ' ' << *v ;
         ~~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~
main.cpp:79:37: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::operator<<<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::vector<ast::algebraic::occupance, std::__1::allocator<ast::algebraic::occupance> > >' requested here
            return os << p.c << " " << p.p;
```

**Question**: how to define the various streaming operators to properly print the matched AST?

Comment: are you using the correct sub-namespace? Or only ast?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's run-of-the-mill ADL. ([What is "Argument-Dependent Lookup" (aka ADL, or "Koenig Lookup")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111677/what-is-argument-dependent-lookup-aka-adl-or-koenig-lookup/8111750#8111750))

Either duplicate the `operator<<` for each subnamespace or use an ADL hook "tag".

### Duplicating

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/98ca4904f3b87ad4)</kbd>**

### ADL Hook

Note the `adl_hook` type and usage:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6f1747493a288a49)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/as_vector.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/io.hpp>
#include <boost/optional/optional_io.hpp>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3/support/ast/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

namespace ast {
    struct adl_hook;

    template <typename T>
        std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, std::vector<T> const& v) {
            os << "{"; for (auto const& el : v) os << el << " "; return os << "}";
        }

    namespace algebraic {

        template <typename tag = adl_hook>
            struct occupance_t
        { 
            char pc; 
            char col;
            int row; 
        };

        using occupance = occupance_t<>;

        using pieces = std::vector<occupance>;

        template <typename tag = adl_hook>
        struct placement_t
        { 
            char c; 
            boost::optional<pieces> p; 
        };        

        using placement = placement_t<>;
    }

    namespace numeric {

        template <typename tag = adl_hook>
        struct occupance_t
        { 
            char pc; 
            int sq; 
        };

        using occupance = occupance_t<>;

        struct range 
        { 
            occupance oc; 
            int sq; 
        };

        using piece  = boost::variant<range, occupance>;
        using pieces = std::vector<piece>;

        template <typename tag = adl_hook>
        struct placement_t
        { 
            char c; 
            boost::optional<pieces> p; 
        };            

        using placement = placement_t<>;
    }

    struct fen 
    { 
        char c; 
        using placement = boost::variant<numeric::placement, algebraic::placement>;
        std::vector<placement> p; 
    };

    namespace algebraic {            
        std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, occupance const& oc)  
        { 
            return os << oc.pc << oc.col << oc.row; 
        }

        std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, placement const& p)     
        { 
            return os << p.c << " " << p.p; 
        }         
    }   // algebriac

    namespace numeric {
        std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, occupance const& oc)  
        { 
            return os << oc.pc << oc.sq; 
        }

        std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, range const& r) 
        { 
            for (auto sq = r.oc.sq; sq <= r.sq; ++sq)
                os << r.oc.pc << sq << " ";
            return os;
        }

        std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, placement const& p)     
        { 
            return os << p.c << " " << p.p; 
        }         
    }   // numeric
}   // ast

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::algebraic::occupance, pc, col, row)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::algebraic::placement, c,  p )

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::numeric::occupance, pc, sq)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::numeric::range,     oc, sq)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::numeric::placement, c,  p )

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::fen, c,  p )

namespace grammar {        
    auto const colon = x3::lit(':');
    auto const comma = x3::lit(',');
    auto const dash  = x3::lit('-');
    auto const dot   = x3::lit('.');

    template<typename T>
    auto as_rule = [](auto p) { return x3::rule<struct _, T>{} = x3::as_parser(p); };

    auto const piece_type = x3::char_('K') | x3::attr('M');
    auto const color      = x3::char_("BW");

    namespace algebraic {        
        auto const square     = x3::lower >> x3::uint_;
        auto const occupance  = as_rule<ast::algebraic::occupance> ( piece_type >> square      ); 
        auto const pieces     = as_rule<ast::algebraic::pieces>    ( occupance % comma         ); 
        auto const placement  = as_rule<ast::algebraic::placement> ( colon >> color >> -pieces );
    }   // algebraic

    namespace numeric {        
        auto const square     = x3::uint_;
        auto const occupance  = as_rule<ast::numeric::occupance> ( piece_type >> square        ); 
        auto const range      = as_rule<ast::numeric::range>     ( occupance >> dash >> square ); 
        auto const pieces     = as_rule<ast::numeric::pieces>    ( (range | occupance) % comma ); 
        auto const placement  = as_rule<ast::numeric::placement> ( colon >> color >> -pieces   );
    }   // numeric

    auto const fen = as_rule<ast::fen> ( color >> (x3::repeat(2)[numeric::placement] | x3::repeat(2)[algebraic::placement]) >> -dot ); 
}   // grammar

int main() {
    for (std::string const t : {
        "W:Wa1,c1,e1,g1,b2,d2,f2,h2,a3,c3,e3,g3:Bb8,d8,f8,h8,a7,c7,e7,g7,b6,d6,f6,h6",
        "W:BKa1,Ka3:WKb8,Kd8",
        "B:W18,24,27,28,K10,K15:B12,16,20,K22,K25,K29",
        "B:W18,19,21,23,24,26,29,30,31,32:B1,2,3,4,6,7,9,10,11,12",
        "W:B1-20:W31-50",   // initial position
        "W:B:W",            // empty board
        "W:B1:W",           // only black pieces
        "W:B:W50"           // only white pieces
    }) {
        auto b = t.begin(), e = t.end();
        ast::fen data;
        bool ok = phrase_parse(b, e, grammar::fen, x3::space, data);

        std::cout << t << "\n";
        if (ok) {
            std::cout << "\t Parsed: \n" << boost::fusion::as_vector(data) << "\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << "Parse failed:\n";
            std::cout << "\t on input: " << t << "\n";
        }
        if (b != e)
            std::cout << "\t Remaining unparsed: '" << std::string(b, e) << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Completed both sample approaches

Comment: try uncommenting also the `<< boost::fusion::as_vector(data)`, then I still get an error (sorry, should have said that in my Q, it was outcommented to silence the compiler)

Comment: [**Fixed²**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ab5e86d9638cb753) (that was a different error, still ADL hooking involved. This time I solved it by making the variants declared inside the actual namespace)

Comment: @TemplateRex [at least one of the `placement`s need also a tag](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e5b674c2fabcbd03).

Comment: Or you can use the approach I did, which seems to be the x3 preferred approach anyways :)

Comment: @cv_and_he yes, your print does print the full parse

Comment: @sehe duplicating is not viable, if both namespace get pulled in, you get an overload resolution ambiguity

Comment: @TemplateRex Something like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b141bfd6d163ffde) could work, although it is not pretty.

Comment: @TemplateRex not true. `use`d names do not participate in ADL. ADL is strictly about the declaring namespace (not saying duplicating is nice, but for that matter I don't think `operator<<` is nice _at all_)

Comment: Re Fixed² I suppose it's because `x3::variant` lacks io? I'm not sure - no time to investigate

Comment: @sehe so if e.g. a `variant<vector<N1::x>, vector<N2::x>>` gets passed to `operator<<(os, variant<T>)`, don't both the `operator(os, vector<T>)` in N1 and N2 get pulled in by ADL?

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot that. Indeed, that would lead to conflict

Comment: @sehe althoug in hindsight, this problem was indeed a familiar theme, but it's not quite *run-of-the-mill* ADL. Usually, ADL is *too greedy*, but here, ordinary lookup on e.g. `boost::variant<numeric::placement, algebraic::placement>` finds an `operator<<` in namespaces `numeric` and `algebraic` and does not proceed the enclosing namespace `ast`. And `ast` is also not an associated namespace (only the immediately enclosing scopes are). Most of the time (99/100?), one is concerned with disabling/limiting ADL, but here it's about encouraging ADL!

Comment: Sounds like run of the mill to me. Associated namespaces are associated namespaces :) I knew it when I wrote it. (It's sometimes almost impossible to get `std::vector` to stream for your types correctly.)

Comment: @sehe I also discovered your stream-tagging technique, that also looks nice and non-intrusive on the types to be streamed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99553/discussion-between-sehe-and-templaterex).

Comment: Fixed the missing adl_hook on `placement`. [see also](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6f1747493a288a49)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the fine answer by @sehe, I decided to side-step all the ADL issues and follow the [**Spirit X3 lecture notes**](https://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjyp6ij843KAhVCKw8KHS4MDfUQFgg4MAM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciere.com%2Fcppnow15%2Fusing_x3.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHYRaO-QH__8ql0zNQUZwkdk1ElvA&sig2=Ot80coG2LJVkjmm77jvzDw) and write a dedicated `printer` class, that loops over `vector` elements by hand.

```
struct printer
{
    std::ostream& out;

    printer(std::ostream& os) : out(os) {}

    auto operator()(algebraic::occupance const& oc) const   
    { 
        out << oc.piece_ << oc.column_ << oc.row_ << " "; 
    }

    auto operator()(std::vector<algebraic::color_placement> const& cps) const    
    { 
        for (auto const& cp : cps) {
            out << " { " << cp.color_ << " : "; 
            for (auto const& elem : cp.placement_)
                (*this)(elem);
            out << " } ";
        }
    }

    auto operator()(numeric::occupance const& oc) const
    { 
        out << oc.piece_ << oc.square_ << " ";
    }

    auto operator()(numeric::range const& r) const
    { 
        auto const occupance = r.occupance_;
        for (auto square = occupance.square_; square <= r.square_; ++square)
            out << occupance.piece_ << square << " ";            
    }

    auto operator()(std::vector<numeric::color_placement> const& cps) const    
    { 
        for (auto const& cp : cps) {
            out << " { " << cp.color_ << " : "; 
            for (auto const& elem : cp.placement_)
                boost::apply_visitor(*this, elem);
            out << " } ";
        }
    }

    auto operator()(fen const& f) const
    {
        out << f.color_; 
        boost::apply_visitor(*this, f.color_placements_);   
    }
};
```

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5d0cfa6cf9795973)</kbd>**

In addition, I cleaned up the grammar a bit by reducing the `boost::optional<std::vector<T>>` to the compatible attribute `std::vector<T>`, so that no more dependencies on `boost::optional` remain.