# parse into vector<boost::string_view> using boost::spirit::x3

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit-x3, string-view

This is a follow-up question to my [previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39225502/parsing-from-stdstring-into-a-booststring-view-using-boostspiritx3) regarding `boost::spirit::x3` and `boost::string_view`.

While I can parse into a `std::vector<std::string>` ([live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6e43d6597d02330d)), parsing into a `std::vector<boost::string_view>` fails with the following compile errors:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <boost/utility/string_view.hpp>

namespace boost {
namespace spirit { namespace x3 { namespace traits {

template <typename It>
void move_to(It b, It e, boost::string_view& v)
{
    v = boost::string_view(b, std::size_t(std::distance(b,e)));
}

} } }

} // namespace boost


#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>

namespace parser
{
    namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;
    using x3::char_;
    using x3::raw;

    const auto str_vec  = *(raw[ +~char_('_')] >> '_');
}

int main()
{
    std::string input = "hello_world_";

    std::vector<boost::string_view> strVec; 
    parse(input.data(), input.data()+input.size(), parser::str_vec, strVec);

    for(auto& x : strVec) { std::cout << x << std::endl; }
}
```

---

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/6.1.0/bits/stl_tempbuf.h:60:0,

                 from /usr/local/include/c++/6.1.0/bits/stl_algo.h:62,

                 from /usr/local/include/c++/6.1.0/algorithm:62,

                 from /usr/local/include/boost/utility/string_view.hpp:27,

                 from main.cpp:4:

/usr/local/include/c++/6.1.0/bits/stl_construct.h: In instantiation of 'void std::_Construct(_T1*, _Args&& ...) [with _T1 = boost::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> >; _Args = {const char&}]':

/usr/local/include/c++/6.1.0/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:75:18:   required from 'static _ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy<_TrivialValueTypes>::__uninit_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = const char*; _ForwardIterator = boost::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> >*; bool _TrivialValueTypes = false]'

/usr/local/include/c++/6.1.0/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:126:15:   required from '_ForwardIterator std::uninitialized_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = const char*; _ForwardIterator = boost::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> >*]'

/usr/local/include/c++/6.1.0/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:281:37:   required from '_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::allocator<_Tp>&) [with _InputIterator = const char*; _ForwardIterator = boost::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> >*; _Tp = boost::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> >]'

/usr/local/include/c++/6.1.0/bits/stl_vector.h:1288:33:   required from 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_range_initialize(_ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::forward_iterator_tag) [with _ForwardIterator = const char*; _Tp = boost::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<boost::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> > >]'

/usr/local/include/c++/6.1.0/bits/stl_vector.h:1261:4:   required from 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_initialize_dispatch(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, std::__false_type) [with _InputIterator = const char*; _Tp = boost::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<boost::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> > >]'

/usr/local/include/c++/6.1.0/bits/stl_vector.h:406:11:   [ skipping 9 instantiation contexts, use -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to disable ]

/usr/local/include/boost/spirit/home/x3/operator/detail/sequence.hpp:496:24:   required from 'static bool boost::spirit::x3::detail::parse_into_container_impl<boost::spirit::x3::sequence<L, R>, Context, RContext>::call(const parser_type&, Iterator&, const Iterator&, const Context&, RContext&, Attribute&) [with Iterator = const char*; Attribute = std::vector<boost::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> > >; Left = boost::spirit::x3::raw_directive<boost::spirit::x3::plus<boost::spirit::x3::negated_char_parser<boost::spirit::x3::literal_char<boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard, char> > > >; Right = boost::spirit::x3::literal_char<boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard, boost::spirit::x3::unused_type>; Context = boost::spirit::x3::unused_type; RContext = const boost::spirit::x3::unused_type; boost::spirit::x3::detail::parse_into_container_impl<boost::spirit::x3::sequence<L, R>, Context, RContext>::parser_type = boost::spirit::x3::sequence<boost::spirit::x3::raw_directive<boost::spirit::x3::plus<boost::spirit::x3::negated_char_parser<boost::spirit::x3::literal_char<boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard, char> > > >, boost::spirit::x3::literal_char<boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard, boost::spirit::x3::unused_type> >]'

/usr/local/include/boost/spirit/home/x3/core/detail/parse_into_container.hpp:287:74:   required from 'bool boost::spirit::x3::detail::parse_into_container(const Parser&, Iterator&, const Iterator&, const Context&, RContext&, Attribute&) [with Parser = boost::spirit::x3::sequence<boost::spirit::x3::raw_directive<boost::spirit::x3::plus<boost::spirit::x3::negated_char_parser<boost::spirit::x3::literal_char<boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard, char> > > >, boost::spirit::x3::literal_char<boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard, boost::spirit::x3::unused_type> >; Iterator = const char*; Context = boost::spirit::x3::unused_type; RContext = const boost::spirit::x3::unused_type; Attribute = std::vector<boost::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> > >]'

/usr/local/include/boost/spirit/home/x3/operator/kleene.hpp:32:48:   required from 'bool boost::spirit::x3::kleene<Subject>::parse(Iterator&, const Iterator&, const Context&, RContext&, Attribute&) const [with Iterator = const char*; Context = boost::spirit::x3::unused_type; RContext = const boost::spirit::x3::unused_type; Attribute = std::vector<boost::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> > >; Subject = boost::spirit::x3::sequence<boost::spirit::x3::raw_directive<boost::spirit::x3::plus<boost::spirit::x3::negated_char_parser<boost::spirit::x3::literal_char<boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard, char> > > >, boost::spirit::x3::literal_char<boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard, boost::spirit::x3::unused_type> >]'

/usr/local/include/boost/spirit/home/x3/core/parse.hpp:35:68:   required from 'bool boost::spirit::x3::parse_main(Iterator&, Iterator, const Parser&, Attribute&) [with Iterator = const char*; Parser = boost::spirit::x3::kleene<boost::spirit::x3::sequence<boost::spirit::x3::raw_directive<boost::spirit::x3::plus<boost::spirit::x3::negated_char_parser<boost::spirit::x3::literal_char<boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard, char> > > >, boost::spirit::x3::literal_char<boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard, boost::spirit::x3::unused_type> > >; Attribute = std::vector<boost::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> > >]'

/usr/local/include/boost/spirit/home/x3/core/parse.hpp:60:26:   required from 'bool boost::spirit::x3::parse(const Iterator&, Iterator, const Parser&, Attribute&) [with Iterator = const char*; Parser = boost::spirit::x3::kleene<boost::spirit::x3::sequence<boost::spirit::x3::raw_directive<boost::spirit::x3::plus<boost::spirit::x3::negated_char_parser<boost::spirit::x3::literal_char<boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard, char> > > >, boost::spirit::x3::literal_char<boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard, boost::spirit::x3::unused_type> > >; Attribute = std::vector<boost::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> > >]'

main.cpp:36:75:   required from here

/usr/local/include/c++/6.1.0/bits/stl_construct.h:75:7: error: no matching function for call to 'boost::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> >::basic_string_view(const char&)'

     { ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }

       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

In file included from main.cpp:4:0:

/usr/local/include/boost/utility/string_view.hpp:82:23: note: candidate: constexpr boost::basic_string_view<charT, traits>::basic_string_view(const charT*) [with charT = char; traits = std::char_traits<char>] <near match>

       BOOST_CONSTEXPR basic_string_view(const charT* str)

                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

/usr/local/include/boost/utility/string_view.hpp:82:23: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:

In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/6.1.0/bits/stl_tempbuf.h:60:0,

                 from /usr/local/include/c++/6.1.0/bits/stl_algo.h:62,

                 from /usr/local/include/c++/6.1.0/algorithm:62,

                 from /usr/local/include/boost/utility/string_view.hpp:27,

                 from main.cpp:4:

/usr/local/include/c++/6.1.0/bits/stl_construct.h:75:7: error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]

     { ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }

       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

In file included from main.cpp:4:0:

/usr/local/include/boost/utility/string_view.hpp:85:23: note: candidate: constexpr boost::basic_string_view<charT, traits>::basic_string_view(const charT*, boost::basic_string_view<charT, traits>::size_type) [with charT = char; traits = std::char_traits<char>; boost::basic_string_view<charT, traits>::size_type = long unsigned int]

       BOOST_CONSTEXPR basic_string_view(const charT* str, size_type len)

                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

/usr/local/include/boost/utility/string_view.hpp:85:23: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided

/usr/local/include/boost/utility/string_view.hpp:78:9: note: candidate: template<class Allocator> boost::basic_string_view<charT, traits>::basic_string_view(const std::__cxx11::basic_string<charT, traits, Allocator>&)

         basic_string_view(const std::basic_string<charT, traits,

         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

/usr/local/include/boost/utility/string_view.hpp:78:9: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:

In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/6.1.0/bits/stl_tempbuf.h:60:0,

                 from /usr/local/include/c++/6.1.0/bits/stl_algo.h:62,

                 from /usr/local/include/c++/6.1.0/algorithm:62,

                 from /usr/local/include/boost/utility/string_view.hpp:27,

                 from main.cpp:4:

/usr/local/include/c++/6.1.0/bits/stl_construct.h:75:7: note:   mismatched types 'const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, Allocator>' and 'const char'

     { ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }

       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

In file included from main.cpp:4:0:

/usr/local/include/boost/utility/string_view.hpp:68:23: note: candidate: constexpr boost::basic_string_view<charT, traits>::basic_string_view(const boost::basic_string_view<charT, traits>&) [with charT = char; traits = std::char_traits<char>]

       BOOST_CONSTEXPR basic_string_view(const basic_string_view &rhs) BOOST_NOEXCEPT

                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

/usr/local/include/boost/utility/string_view.hpp:68:23: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const char' to 'const boost::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> >&'

/usr/local/include/boost/utility/string_view.hpp:65:23: note: candidate: constexpr boost::basic_string_view<charT, traits>::basic_string_view() [with charT = char; traits = std::char_traits<char>]

       BOOST_CONSTEXPR basic_string_view() BOOST_NOEXCEPT

                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

/usr/local/include/boost/utility/string_view.hpp:65:23: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided

In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/6.1.0/bits/char_traits.h:39:0,

                 from /usr/local/include/c++/6.1.0/ios:40,

                 from /usr/local/include/c++/6.1.0/ostream:38,

                 from /usr/local/include/c++/6.1.0/iostream:39,

                 from main.cpp:1:

/usr/local/include/c++/6.1.0/bits/stl_algobase.h: In instantiation of 'static _OI std::__copy_move<false, false, std::random_access_iterator_tag>::__copy_m(_II, _II, _OI) [with _II = const char*; _OI = boost::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> >*]':

/usr/local/include/c++/6.1.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:386:44:   required from '_OI std::__copy_move_a(_II, _II, _OI) [with bool _IsMove = false; _II = const char*; _OI = boost::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> >*]'

/usr/local/include/c++/6.1.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:422:45:   required from '_OI std::__copy_move_a2(_II, _II, _OI) [with bool _IsMove = false; _II = const char*; _OI = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<boost::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> >*, std::vector<boost::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> > > >]'

/usr/local/include/c++/6.1.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:455:8:   required from '_OI std::copy(_II, _II, _OI) [with _II = const char*; _OI = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<boost::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> >*, std::vector<boost::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> > > >]'

/usr/local/include/c++/6.1.0/bits/vector.tcc:637:16:   required from 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_range_insert(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator, _ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::forward_iterator_tag) [with _ForwardIterator = const char*; _Tp = boost::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<boost::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> > >; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<boost::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> >*, std::vector<boost::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> > > >; typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::pointer = boost::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> >*]'

/usr/local/include/c++/6.1.0/bits/stl_vector.h:1375:4:   required from 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_insert_dispatch(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator, _InputIterator, _InputIterator, std::__false_type) [with _InputIterator = const char*; _Tp = boost::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<boost::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> > >; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<boost::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> >*, std::vector<boost::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> > > >; typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::pointer = boost::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> >*]'

/usr/local/include/c++/6.1.0/bits/stl_vector.h:1100:4:   [ skipping 12 instantiation contexts, use -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to disable ]

/usr/local/include/boost/spirit/home/x3/operator/detail/sequence.hpp:496:24:   required from 'static bool boost::spirit::x3::detail::parse_into_container_impl<boost::spirit::x3::sequence<L, R>, Context, RContext>::call(const parser_type&, Iterator&, const Iterator&, const Context&, RContext&, Attribute&) [with Iterator = const char*; Attribute = std::vector<boost::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> > >; Left = boost::spirit::x3::raw_directive<boost::spirit::x3::plus<boost::spirit::x3::negated_char_parser<boost::spirit::x3::literal_char<boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard, char> > > >; Right = boost::spirit::x3::literal_char<boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard, boost::spirit::x3::unused_type>; Context = boost::spirit::x3::unused_type; RContext = const boost::spirit::x3::unused_type; boost::spirit::x3::detail::parse_into_container_impl<boost::spirit::x3::sequence<L, R>, Context, RContext>::parser_type = boost::spirit::x3::sequence<boost::spirit::x3::raw_directive<boost::spirit::x3::plus<boost::spirit::x3::negated_char_parser<boost::spirit::x3::literal_char<boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard, char> > > >, boost::spirit::x3::literal_char<boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard, boost::spirit::x3::unused_type> >]'

/usr/local/include/boost/spirit/home/x3/core/detail/parse_into_container.hpp:287:74:   required from 'bool boost::spirit::x3::detail::parse_into_container(const Parser&, Iterator&, const Iterator&, const Context&, RContext&, Attribute&) [with Parser = boost::spirit::x3::sequence<boost::spirit::x3::raw_directive<boost::spirit::x3::plus<boost::spirit::x3::negated_char_parser<boost::spirit::x3::literal_char<boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard, char> > > >, boost::spirit::x3::literal_char<boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard, boost::spirit::x3::unused_type> >; Iterator = const char*; Context = boost::spirit::x3::unused_type; RContext = const boost::spirit::x3::unused_type; Attribute = std::vector<boost::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> > >]'

/usr/local/include/boost/spirit/home/x3/operator/kleene.hpp:32:48:   required from 'bool boost::spirit::x3::kleene<Subject>::parse(Iterator&, const Iterator&, const Context&, RContext&, Attribute&) const [with Iterator = const char*; Context = boost::spirit::x3::unused_type; RContext = const boost::spirit::x3::unused_type; Attribute = std::vector<boost::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> > >; Subject = boost::spirit::x3::sequence<boost::spirit::x3::raw_directive<boost::spirit::x3::plus<boost::spirit::x3::negated_char_parser<boost::spirit::x3::literal_char<boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard, char> > > >, boost::spirit::x3::literal_char<boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard, boost::spirit::x3::unused_type> >]'

/usr/local/include/boost/spirit/home/x3/core/parse.hpp:35:68:   required from 'bool boost::spirit::x3::parse_main(Iterator&, Iterator, const Parser&, Attribute&) [with Iterator = const char*; Parser = boost::spirit::x3::kleene<boost::spirit::x3::sequence<boost::spirit::x3::raw_directive<boost::spirit::x3::plus<boost::spirit::x3::negated_char_parser<boost::spirit::x3::literal_char<boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard, char> > > >, boost::spirit::x3::literal_char<boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard, boost::spirit::x3::unused_type> > >; Attribute = std::vector<boost::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> > >]'

/usr/local/include/boost/spirit/home/x3/core/parse.hpp:60:26:   required from 'bool boost::spirit::x3::parse(const Iterator&, Iterator, const Parser&, Attribute&) [with Iterator = const char*; Parser = boost::spirit::x3::kleene<boost::spirit::x3::sequence<boost::spirit::x3::raw_directive<boost::spirit::x3::plus<boost::spirit::x3::negated_char_parser<boost::spirit::x3::literal_char<boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard, char> > > >, boost::spirit::x3::literal_char<boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard, boost::spirit::x3::unused_type> > >; Attribute = std::vector<boost::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> > >]'

main.cpp:36:75:   required from here

/usr/local/include/c++/6.1.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:324:18: error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'boost::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> >' and 'const char')

        *__result = *__first;

        ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~

In file included from main.cpp:4:0:

/usr/local/include/boost/utility/string_view.hpp:71:26: note: candidate: boost::basic_string_view<charT, traits>& boost::basic_string_view<charT, traits>::operator=(const boost::basic_string_view<charT, traits>&) [with charT = char; traits = std::char_traits<char>]

       basic_string_view& operator=(const basic_string_view &rhs) BOOST_NOEXCEPT {

                          ^~~~~~~~

/usr/local/include/boost/utility/string_view.hpp:71:26: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const char' to 'const boost::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> >&'
```

**[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ff90f92705a147ed)**

What am I missing here?

Comment: `string_view` does not own the memory it references. So... who does?

Comment: @NicolBolas the memory here is owned by `std::string input`; but why does this matter regarding the compiler error?

Comment: I have no idea why that exact error occurs but I can say that forcing the attribute of `raw[...]` to be a `boost::string_view` [makes it work](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/9i7TahRuri1OfX1y). You can either manually use an extra rule (`x3::rule<class my_rule,boost::string_ref> my_rule= x3::raw[....]; auto const str_vec=*my_rule;`) or use the `as` approach I show in the example which I have seen sehe use several times ([here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34561232/2417774) for example) which in the end is the same.

Comment: @jv_ I've seen this kind of syntax where there is an intermediate, explicit rule which specifies the attribute ([this](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/OJrQSvHttB64cAAi) works for me as well); I wonder why this is necessary sometimes and sometimes it is not ...

Comment: Probably the "magic" required to make sure the concatenation of strings works is greedier than it should. Unfortunately I don't know enough about X3 to say for certain.

Comment: AFAICT the problem seems to be that the Spirit.X3 machinery tests whether the synthesized attribute of `raw` (technically `boost::iterator_range<char*>`, but apparently at that moment still `raw_attribute_type`) is a substitute for the value_type of your attribute (the value type is `boost::string_view`). That test fails and X3 takes the wrong code path and tries unsuccessfully to manipulate the attributes to make them fit. Making `x3::traits::is_substitute<raw_attribute_type,boost::string_ref>` be true, makes the whole thing [work again](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/9vUBT2WZ895sZvqv).

Comment: @jv_ is this a documented extension point?

Comment: The documentation for X3 is sadly lacking, but I don't think it was even in Qi. It is a big part of what makes Spirit's attribute propagation work. [This thread](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Problem-with-x3-variant-tp4667410.html) shows a similar situation (initially solved with the extra rule workaround) and [this message from Joel de Guzman](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Problem-with-x3-variant-tp4667410p4667461.html) talks about `is_substitute`. PS: In my previous comment I meant `boost::string_view` when I said `boost::string_ref`.

Comment: @jv_ if you'd make an answer out of your comments, I'd accept that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By overloading/specializing `move_to` you are basically telling X3 how to convert from a `boost::iterator_range` (actually just a pair of iterators) to `boost::string_view`. Unfortunately it doesn't know that both are "equivalent" (one is a `substitute` of the other seems to be the nomenclature used in Spirit). And so your original example works because you are explicitly requesting the transformation from iterators to `string_view` but this one fails since X3 lacks the required information to infer the appropriate attribute type.

Especifically the problem seems to be [here](https://github.com/boostorg/spirit/blob/boost-1.61.0/include/boost/spirit/home/x3/core/detail/parse_into_container.hpp#L268), where it is tested whether the attribute of the parser (in this case `raw_attribute_type`) is compatible with the value_type of the expected attribute (`boost::string_view`). This test fails and then a code path where the attribute is not "passed as is" is chosen causing the error you get.

With all this in mind there seem to be two possible approaches: either explicitly request the transformation or provide Spirit with the information about the compatibility of the attributes.

Missing some of the helpers we had in Qi (`attr_cast`, `as[]`) it seems that the way to force an attribute transformation in X3 is by creating an extra rule with the actual type you want:

```
x3::rule<class str,boost::string_view> str= x3::raw[ +~char_('_')] >> '_';
auto const str_vec = *str;
```

You could also (especially if you need to do this in several rules) use an approach I've seen sehe use several times (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37204957/2417774)) that creates a variable template lambda that can be used like `as<T>(parser)` that hides the creation of that extra rule and forces the attribute of `parser` to transform into `T`.

```
template<typename T>
auto as = [](auto p) { return rule<struct _, T>{} = as_parser(p); };
auto const str_vec = *as<boost::string_view>(x3::raw[ +~char_('_')] >> '_');
```

The way to provide Spirit with the information about the compatibility of the attributes seems to be to specialize `x3::traits::is_substitute`:

```
namespace boost {
namespace spirit { namespace x3 { namespace traits { 
    template <>
    struct is_substitute<raw_attribute_type,boost::string_view> : boost::mpl::true_
    {};
}}}
}
```

But as you mentioned in the comments this doesn't seem to be a documented customization point and so I'm not sure if it's a good idea to use it. Ideally this would be specialized by default in X3, but as sehe commented in the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39225502/parsing-from-stdstring-into-a-booststring-view-using-boostspiritx3), the fact that the storage referred by the iterators must be contiguous complicates the situation.