# Spirit.X3 using string_view and member named 'insert' compiler error

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit-x3

At Stackoverflow there are several Questions & Answers which are related to use `{boost, std}::string_view`, e.g.:

- [parsing from std::string into a boost::string_view using boost::spirit::x3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39225502/parsing-from-stdstring-into-a-booststring-view-using-boostspiritx3?answertab=active#tab-top) with overloading x3's `move_to`

  ```
  namespace boost { namespace spirit { namespace x3 { namespace traits {

  template <typename It>
  void move_to(It b, It e, boost::string_view& v)
  {
      v = boost::string_view(&*b, e-b);
  }

  } } } }
  ```
- [parse into vector using boost::spirit::x3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39230186/parse-into-vectorbooststring-view-using-boostspiritx3?answertab=active#tab-top) where further the information about the compatibility of the attributes is given

  ```
  namespace boost { namespace spirit { namespace x3 { namespace traits { 
      template <>
      struct is_substitute<raw_attribute_type,boost::string_view> : boost::mpl::true_
      {};
  } } } }
  ```

llonesmiz wrote an example at [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/9vUBT2WZ895sZvqv) which compiles with [boost 1.64](https://wandbox.org/permlink/SLkvZGUr4OxTVMGw), but failed with [boost 1.67](https://wandbox.org/permlink/CeWFqOfFq2Okbnio) now with

```
    opt/wandbox/boost-1.67.0/gcc-7.3.0/include/boost/spirit/home/x3/support/traits/container_traits.hpp:177:15: error: 'class boost::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> >' has no member named 'insert'
                 c.insert(c.end(), first, last);
                 ~~^~~~~~
```

the same error I faced in my project.

The problem raises also by use of `std::string`
even with the explicite use of [Sehe's as<> "directive"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33816662/understanding-the-list-operator-in-boost-spirit?answertab=active#tab-top), see also at [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/dJxe2cCS1qg6ekyn):

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <string_view>

    namespace boost { namespace spirit { namespace x3 { namespace traits {

    template <typename It>
    void move_to(It b, It e, std::string_view& v)
    {
        v = std::string_view(&*b, e-b);
    }

    } } } } // namespace boost


    #include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>


    namespace boost { namespace spirit { namespace x3 { namespace traits {

    template <>
    struct is_substitute<raw_attribute_type, std::string_view> : boost::mpl::true_
    {};

    } } } } // namespace boost


    namespace parser
    {
        namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;
        using x3::char_;
        using x3::raw;

        template<typename T>
        auto as = [](auto p) { return x3::rule<struct _, T>{ "as" } = x3::as_parser(p); };

        const auto str = as<std::string_view>(raw[ +~char_('_')] >> '_');
        const auto str_vec  = *str;
    }

    int main()
    {
        std::string input = "hello_world_";

        std::vector<std::string_view> strVec; 
        boost::spirit::x3::parse(input.data(), input.data()+input.size(), parser::str_vec, strVec);

        for(auto& x : strVec) { std::cout << x << std::endl; }
    }
```

As far I've seen, the problem starts with boost 1.65. What has been changed and how to fix it?

Finaly, I've a question about the requirement of contiguous storage mentioned by [sehe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39225502/parsing-from-stdstring-into-a-booststring-view-using-boostspiritx3?answertab=active#tab-top): I understand the requirements of this, but does the parser can violate this? - In my opinion the parser has to fail even on backtracking, so this can't happen by spirit. By use of the error_handler,  the memory storage address which refers the string_view is at last on parse level valid. I conclude it's save to use string_view as far the references are in the scope under this condition, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here seems to be with the `is_container` trait:

```
template <typename T>
using is_container = mpl::bool_<
    detail::has_type_value_type<T>::value &&
    detail::has_type_iterator<T>::value &&
    detail::has_type_size_type<T>::value &&
    detail::has_type_reference<T>::value>;
```

In Qi, that would have been specializable:

```
template <> struct is_container<std::string_view> : std::false_type {};
```

However in X3 it started being a template alias, which cannot be specialized.

This is a tough issue, as it seems that there is simply no customization point to get X3 to do what we need here.

### Workaround

I've tried to dig deeper. I have not seen a "clean" way around this. In fact, the attribute coercion trick *can* help, though, if you use it to "short out" the heuristic that causes the match:

- the attribute is "like a" container of "char"
- the parser could match such a container

In this situation we can coerce the parser's attribute to *specifically* be non-compatible, and things will start working.

### Correctly Overriding `move_to`

This, too, is an area of contention. Simply *adding* the overload like:

```
template <typename It>
inline void move_to(It b, It e, std::string_view& v) {
    v = std::string_view(&*b, std::distance(b,e));
}
```

is not enough to make it the best overload.

The base template is

```
template <typename Iterator, typename Dest>
inline void move_to(Iterator first, Iterator last, Dest& dest);
```

To actually make it stick, we need to *specialize*. However, specializing and function templates [is not a good match](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm). In particular, we can't partially specialize, so we'll end up hard-coding the template arguments:

```
template <>
inline void move_to<Iterator, std::string_view>(Iterator b, Iterator e, std::string_view& v) {
    v = std::string_view(&*b, std::distance(b,e));
}
```

> This is making me question whether `move_to` is "user-serviceable" at all, much like `is_container<>` above, it just seems not designed for extension.
>
> I do realize I've applied it in the past myself, but I also learn as I go.

### Coercing: Hacking the System

Instead of declaring the rule's attribute `std::string_view` (leaving X3's type magic room to "do the <strike>right</strike> thing"), let's etch in stone the intended outcome of `raw[]` (and leave X3 to do the rest of the magic using `move_to`):

```
namespace parser {
    namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;
    const auto str 
        = x3::rule<struct _, boost::iterator_range<Iterator> >{"str"}
        = x3::raw[ +~x3::char_('_')] >> '_';
    const auto str_vec  = *str;
}
```

This works. See it **<kbd>[Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/avwX5B8rTtEbOxQk)</kbd>**

Prints

```
hello
world
```

### Alternative

That seems brittle. E.g. it'll break if you [change `Iterator` to `char const*`](https://wandbox.org/permlink/J3SARcSwMKL0JoN3) (or, [use `std::string const`](https://wandbox.org/permlink/z7yyGQpaowk1VART) `input = "hello_world_"`, but not [both](https://wandbox.org/permlink/DOi7je4432Z9cFDX)).

Here's a better take (I think):

```
namespace boost { namespace spirit { namespace x3 {

    template <typename Char, typename CharT, typename Iterator> 
    struct default_transform_attribute<std::basic_string_view<Char, CharT>, boost::iterator_range<Iterator>> {
        using type = boost::iterator_range<Iterator>;

        template <typename T> static type pre(T&&) { return {}; }

        static void post(std::basic_string_view<Char, CharT>& sv, boost::iterator_range<Iterator> const& r) {
            sv = std::basic_string_view<Char, CharT>(std::addressof(*r.begin()), r.size());
        }
    };

} } }
```

Now, the only hoop left to jump is that the rule declaration mentions the iterator type. You can hide this too:

```
namespace parser {
    namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

    template <typename It> const auto str_vec = [] {
        const auto str 
            = x3::rule<struct _, boost::iterator_range<It> >{"str"}
            = x3::raw[ +~x3::char_('_')] >> '_';
        return *str;
    }();
}

auto parse(std::string_view input) {
    auto b = input.begin(), e = input.end();
    std::vector<std::string_view> data;
    parse(b, e, parser::str_vec<decltype(b)>, data);
    return data;
}

int main() {
    for(auto& x : parse("hello_world_"))
        std::cout << x << "\n";
}
```

This at once demonstrates that it works with non-pointer iterators.

> Note: for completeness you'd want to statically assert the iterator models the [ContiguousIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ContiguousIterator) concept (c++17)

### Final Version Live

**[Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/gViS5UQ5qzzZJS96)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>

namespace boost { namespace spirit { namespace x3 {

    template <typename Char, typename CharT, typename Iterator> 
    struct default_transform_attribute<std::basic_string_view<Char, CharT>, boost::iterator_range<Iterator>> {
        using type = boost::iterator_range<Iterator>;

        template <typename T> static type pre(T&&) { return {}; }

        static void post(std::basic_string_view<Char, CharT>& sv, boost::iterator_range<Iterator> const& r) {
            sv = std::basic_string_view<Char, CharT>(std::addressof(*r.begin()), r.size());
        }
    };

} } }

namespace parser {
    namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

    template <typename It> const auto str_vec = [] {
        const auto str 
            = x3::rule<struct _, boost::iterator_range<It> >{"str"}
            = x3::raw[ +~x3::char_('_')] >> '_';
        return *str;
    }();
}

auto parse(std::string_view input) {
    auto b = input.begin(), e = input.end();
    std::vector<std::string_view> data;
    parse(b, e, parser::str_vec<decltype(b)>, data);
    return data;
}

int main() {
    for(auto& x : parse("hello_world_"))
        std::cout << x << "\n";
}
```

Comment: That the rule declaration mentions the iterator type is a burden since I implement a BNF using the style shown by the x3 examples e.g. calc9, but with ~300 rules. I have to carry the iterator type up to the top level rule. A solution would be to use the typedef [e.g. from parser config](https://github.com/boostorg/spirit/blob/develop/example/x3/calc/calc9/config.hpp) and parametrize the `string_view` rules. Otherwise, this problem with `string_view` rises from time to time until `string_view` is a first citizen member of x3 as of e.g. `std::vector`.
The best is probably to use x3::raw as is.

Comment: ... and use iterator_range with the iterator to be instanced later. Anyway, your answer solves the problem!

Comment: Oh, yeah it's a pity, and you can fight your way out of the corner using enough template meta-programming. However, for now I think my quick fix shown under "You can hide this too:" already achieves the goal of "don't repeat yourself" w.r.t. the iterator type.

Comment: And I agree that there is a problem to be fixed with attribute forwaring to string_view in x3, if you can postpone the "neat" solution until such a time, that's probably wise. Do consider filing an issue at the mailing list or https://github.com/boostorg/spirit