# Boost.x3: attribute accumulates between alternatives

Tags: c++, parsing, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-x3

I have a parser for parsing an Identifier like `foo, bar, baz` and one for parsing also nested identifiers like `foo::bar, foo::bar.baz, foo::bar.baz.baham`
They both parse into the same ast struct, which looks like this:

```
struct identifier : x3::position_tagged{
    std::vector <std::string> namespaces;
    std::vector <std::string> classes;
    std::string identifier;

};
```

The parser for an `identifier` looks like this:

```
#define VEC_ATR x3::attr(std::vector<std::string>({})) //ugly hack

auto const identifier_def =
                VEC_ATR
                >> VEC_ATR
                >> id_string;
```

and for the `nested_identifier` like this:

```
auto const nested_identifier_def =
        x3::lexeme[
                (+(id_string >> "::") >> +(id_string >> ".") > id_string)
                | (+(id_string >> "::") >> VEC_ATR > id_string)
                | (VEC_ATR >> +(id_string >> ".") > id_string)
                | identifier

        ];
```

I know shame on me for the macro.
The identifier parser works fine, but the 
 `nested_identifier` has a strange behaviour
if I try to parse something like `foo::bar::baz` the ast objects which falls out of the parser, has all the namespaces, in this case `foo` and `bar` twice in the `namespaces` vector.
I have a small example of this strange behaviour
[here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c829d3c9932a35c8).
Can anybody explain me why this happens, and how I can avoid this?

Comment: what makes it useful to distinguis classes from namespaces? E.g. in C++, classes _are_ namespaces.

Comment: you are right, I wanted the ast to hold as much information as I could get. Thats why i parse an id followed by a dot into the classes vector. maybe classes isnt the best name, but I couldnt find another quick

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason why you get that behaviour is that the alternative parser does not automatically rollback the changes made to the external attribute when one of its branches fails.

In your case this is what happens:

> - Initially the attribute is `[{},{},""]`.
> - The first alternative branch is tried.
> - `id_string >> "::"` matches twice and adds `foo` and `bar` to the first vector ->`[{foo,bar},{},""]`.
> - `id_string >> "."` fails to match -> the sequence fails -> the alternative branch fails (leaving the attribute unchanged).
> - The second alternative branch is tried.
> - `id_string >> "::"` matches twice and adds `foo` and `bar` to the first vector ->`[{foo,bar,foo,bar},{},""]`.
> - `attr(vector<string>({}))` succeeds (`attr` always succeeds) and substitutes the empty second vector with a vector with an empty string -> `[{foo,bar,foo,bar},{""},""]`.
> - `id_string` matches and `baz` is added to the attribute ->`[{foo,bar,foo,bar},{""},baz]`.
> - The second alternative branch succeeds.

In Spirit.Qi the solution in this case is quite easy, simply use the [hold directive](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/directive/hold.html). Unfortunately this directive is not yet implemented in Spirit.X3. A possible alternative could be putting each of the alternative branches in its own `x3::rule` either explicitly or with `as<ast::identifier>(alternative_branch)` as used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34561232/2417774) by sehe. [Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2aa67603f92d5b16) is a simplified example that shows the `as` approach.

Another possibility could be implementing the `hold` directive, here is my attempt([running on WandBox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/PX4fRCuxEKjdGCig)):

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3/support/context.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3/core/skip_over.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3/core/parser.hpp>

namespace boost { namespace spirit { namespace x3
{
    template <typename Subject>
    struct hold_directive : unary_parser<Subject, hold_directive<Subject>>
    {
        typedef unary_parser<Subject, hold_directive<Subject> > base_type;
        static bool const is_pass_through_unary = true;
        static bool const handles_container = Subject::handles_container;

        hold_directive(Subject const& subject)
          : base_type(subject) {}

        template <typename Iterator, typename Context
          , typename RContext, typename Attribute>
        bool parse(Iterator& first, Iterator const& last
          , Context const& context, RContext& rcontext, Attribute& attr) const
        {
            Attribute copy(attr);
            if (this->subject.parse(first, last, context, rcontext, copy))
            {
                traits::move_to(copy, attr);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    };

    struct hold_gen
    {
        template <typename Subject>
        hold_directive<typename extension::as_parser<Subject>::value_type>
        operator[](Subject const& subject) const
        {
            return { as_parser(subject) };
        }
    };

    auto const hold = hold_gen{};
}}}
```

Comment: never used this `as<something>` before. how does it work?
thank you a lot for your help, I wasnt expecting this behaviour.

Comment: I think it links to the place where it's explained :)

Comment: oh sorry I was to fast

Comment: @Exagon [Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2aa67603f92d5b16) is a simplified example that shows the `as` approach.

Comment: @sehe and jv_ I would be screwd without you two, thank you for helping me all the time with spirit

Comment: @sehe, why have your working as and hold parsers not been added to x3?....

Comment: @rmawatson I didn't propose them. I reckon if they would, they'd add them in low-level style. The whole point for me is that you don't need special library support for these, as they're pretty easily expressed in c++14

Comment: @rmawatson More testament to the versatility of C++14 with X3: [porting a subset of phoenix for semantic actions into X3](https://github.com/sehe/expression-parsers/blob/x3-c%2B%2B17/phoeni_x3.hpp)

Comment: @sehe be really great to see them merged in. Shame to have such useful bits floating about on SO.

Comment: I'm in favor of libraries with a maintainable documented interface. Picking the right core set to maintain is not an easy task.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that as of Boost1.70, the solution proposed by @sehe does not work anymore (see [this discussion](https://github.com/boostorg/spirit/issues/523)).

The only workaround now is to refactor the grammar, so that the rollback wouldn't be needed.