# Spirit: discarding attribute during backtracking

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-x3

I don't understand the behaviour of x3 in the following example (taken from a larger grammar).

The grammar is a bit weird, granted, but roughly it implements `(lal)?(<char>)?`.  When the second group is not present, it defaults to `<default>`.  I don't understand why on the input `"lal<char>"` I get `defaultchar` as a result:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/config/warning_disable.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_pair.hpp>

int main()
{
  namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;
  namespace ascii = boost::spirit::x3::ascii;

  using ascii::alnum;
  using ascii::char_;
  using ascii::space;
  using x3::attr;
  using x3::eoi;
  using x3::lexeme;
  using x3::lit;
  using x3::string;

  const auto letter
    = lit("<") >> string("char") >> lit('>')
    | attr(std::string{"default"})
    ;

  const auto letterset
    = letter >> eoi
    | lit("lal") >> letter >> eoi
    ;

  for (std::string i: {"", "<char>", "lal", "lal<char>"})
    {
      auto res = std::string{};
      auto first = i.cbegin();
      auto last = i.cend();
      auto r = x3::phrase_parse(first, last, letterset, space, res);
      if (r && first == last)
        std::cout << i << ": " << res << '\n';
      else
        std::cout << i << ": failed\n";
    }
}
```

result:

```
: default
<char>: char
lal: defaultdefault
lal<char>: defaultchar
```

I do notice that if I swap the alternatives of `letterset`, then I get the expected result, which is probably a sign that's related to backtracking: in the original case I get the `default` from its first attempt, and the `char` from the second one, successful.

I'm very tempted to call this a bug, but I'm an x3 newbie...

This is X3 from Boost 1.65.

Thanks in advance @sehe :)

Comment: It's seems that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39537675/strange-behaviour-of-parser-with-boost-spirit-x3 has hints on what is going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you've hit a side effect of backtracking. Spirit parsers append their results if attribute is a container (`std::string` is a container), but if a branch fails the container is not cleared.

There is `hold` directive in `Qi` to deal with it, but not in `X3`. I will look what I can do to `X3`, I think there are some solutions with close to zero overhead without the horrible `hold` directive.

The general suggestion is to try to rewrite you grammar to not backtrack, but if it is impossible you may use a workaround (it should be a slightly more performant alternative to `hold`):

```
const auto recover_from_backtrack = (rule<class _, std::string>{} = eps) /
    [](auto const& ctx) { x3::_attr(ctx).clear(); x3::_pass(ctx) = false; };

const auto letterset
    = letter >> eoi
    | recover_from_backtrack
    | lit("lal") >> letter >> eoi
    ;
```

Comment: So is it considered "ok" that backtracking leaves side-effects in x3's own generated attributes?  As a simple user, I definitely see that as a bug^H^H^Hmisfeature.

Comment: I agree with you and I am going to change it. More info here https://github.com/boostorg/spirit/issues/378